# Highcharts steps to setup own server for download

Tags: python, django, highcharts, server, export

I want to create a application which will generate some report based on some data and analysis.
And I have to create a graph for this report.

I'm using Django framework with python to generate report and Highchart for graphs.
But after using highchart,js i realised that .js uses export.highcharts.com
I do not want to send the data to export.highcharts.com but use my server. How can i acheive this ?

Im very new to this and just started learning Django. Finding it difficult to understand the explaination given  here :
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server.

So once i download highcharts-export-server what are the next steps ?
What changes am i supposed to do in highchart.js file so that download options are available.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple 1-2-3 of testing a initial usage of `highcharts-export-server` could be this:

1. Install the server package:

   ```
   npm install highcharts-export-server -g
   ```
2. Run the server, for example:

   ```
   highcharts-export-server --enableServer 1
   ```

   This should lead to output similar to this:

   ```
       __  ___       __         __               __                      
      / / / (_)___ _/ /_  _____/ /_  ____ ______/ /______                
     / /_/ / / __ `/ __ \/ ___/ __ \/ __ `/ ___/ __/ ___/                
    / __  / / /_/ / / / / /__/ / / / /_/ / /  / /_(__  )                 
   /_/ /_/_/\__, /_/ /_/\___/_/ /_/\__,_/_/   \__/____/                  
           ____//___/                  __     _____                          
          / ____/  ______  ____  _____/ /_   / ___/___  ______   _____  _____
         / __/ | |/_/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ __/   \__ \/ _ \/ ___/ | / / _ \/ ___/
        / /____>  </ /_/ / /_/ / /  / /_    ___/ /  __/ /   | |/ /  __/ /    
       /_____/_/|_/ .___/\____/_/   \__/   /____/\___/_/    |___/\___/_/     
                 /_/                                                         

                                                                     v2.0.16
   ```

   ([Read about the parameter for the server here](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/README.md#command-line-arguments))
3. Change your exporting URL in your chart config:

   ```
   exporting: {
       url: "http://localhost:7801"
   }
   ```

You should now be able to use the "Download PNG image" context menu button, if you have included the `exporting.js` script for your Highcharts.

You will need to do more specific arguments for network/production use, which the link in step 2 will help you with.

Comment: it might seem silly again but which chart config file. I dont find any such file where i can add 
exporting: {
    url: "http://localhost:7801"
}

Comment: @Rachel how are you creating your chart, with options? If you were creating your options as a JSON object then you'd simply add the segment to your options. For example in plain javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/wcaLfyq3/. If you use some sort of wrapper, I'm guessing it might still be similar to that just through objects instead.